# Using Pyomo Kernel to solve Disjunctive models

Tags: python-3.x, binary, linear-programming, pyomo

I am trying to recreate a problem in the "Pyomo - Optimization Modeling in Python" book using the pyomo kernel instead of the environ. The problem is on page 163 and called "9.4 A mixing problem with semi-continuous variables." For those without the book, here it is:

*The following model illustrates a simple mixing problem with three semi-continuous
variables (x1, x2, x3) which represent quantities that are mixed to meet a volumetric
constraint. In this simple example, the number of sources is minimized:*

```
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.gdp import *
L = [1,2,3]
U = [2,4,6]

index = [0,1,2]
model = ConcreteModel()
model.x = Var(index, within=Reals, bounds=(0,20))
# Each disjunct is a semi-continuous variable
# x[k] == 0 or L[k] <= x[k] <= U[k]
def d_rule(block, k, i):
    m = block.model()
    if i == 0:
        block.c = Constraint(expr=m.x[k] == 0)
    else:
        block.c = Constraint(expr=L[k] <= m.x[k] <= U[k])
model.d = Disjunct(index, [0,1], rule=d_rule)
# There are three disjunctions
def D_rule(block, k):
    model = block.model()
    return [model.d[k,0], model.d[k,1]]
model.D = Disjunction(index, rule=D_rule)
# Minimize the number of x variables that are nonzero
model.o = Objective(expr=sum(model.d[k,1].indicator_var for k in index))
# Satisfy a demand that is met by these variables
model.c = Constraint(expr=sum(model.x[k] for k in index) >= 7)
```

I need to refactor this problem to work in the pyomo kernel, but the kernel is not yet compatible with the pyomo gdp used to transform disjunctive models to linear ones. Has anyone ran into this problem, and if so did you find a good method to solve disjunctive models in the pyomo kernel?

Comment: have you resolved this?  I have a related question regarding pyomo.kernel extending to ROmodel:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72468776/is-pyomo-kernel-compatible-with-romodel.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have a partial rewrite of pyomo.gdp that I could make available on a public github branch (probably working, but lacks testing). However, I am weary of investing more time in rewrites like this, as the better approach would be to re-implement the standard pyomo.environ api on top of kernel, which would make all of the extensions compatible.

With that being said, If there are collaborators willing to share in some of the development and testing, I would be happy help complete the kernel-gdp version I've started. If you want to discuss this further, it would probably be best to open an [issue](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues) on the Pyomo Github page.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Quick question: Do you have any idea if/when models built using `pyomo.kernel` will be compatible with pyomo extension modules (e.g.; `pyomo.gdp`)? I'm considering refactoring a module that uses the `pyomo.kernel` to use the `pyomo.environ`, but I'm curious if/when the `pyomo.kernel` will be supported.

Comment: Somewhat realted:  I'm also wondering if pyomo.kernel is compatible with ROmodel (https://github.com/cog-imperial/romodel).  Anyone know?